# Turning objects DataSource to a List<>

Tags: asp.net

Attempting to take the data in my gridview and convert it back into a list so I can run an update function. Currently I'm getting a null value when I attempt this.

```
List<CodeEntity> codes = new List<CodeEntity>();

codes = (List<CodeEntity>)Convert.ChangeType(gdvFGCode.DataSource,typeof(List<CodeEntity>));

Response.Write(codes[0].FGCode);
```

Also, Since the Gridview contains 3 template fields all with controls inside, would the datasource returned contain the updated values from the controls or would it return the original List<> pasted into it.

EDIT: The class I'm attempting to return in the list

```
public class CodeEntity
{

    private string _fgCode;

    private Int16 _palletSet;

    private bool _priority;

    private int _codeState;

    private string _formingCode;

    private string _d4Code;

    public string FGCode
    {
        get { return _fgCode; }
        set { _fgCode = value; }
    }
    public int CodeState
    {
        get { return _codeState; }
        set { _codeState = value; }
    }
    public Int16 PalletSet
    {
        get { return _palletSet; }
        set { _palletSet = value; }
    }
    public bool Priority
    {
        get { return _priority; }
        set { _priority = value; }
    }
    public string FormingCode
    {
        get { return _formingCode; }
        set { _formingCode = value; }
    }
    public string D4Code
    {
        get { return _d4Code; }
        set { _d4Code = value; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you binding the `List<CodeEntity>` to dgvFGCode initially?

Comment: Yes, just doing a simply .DataSource .Databind to populate the gridview

Comment: Trying to eliminate the obivous here, so bear with me.  Have you verified that the DataSource is not null when you attempt to copy it to the new `List<CodeEntity>`?  Since you originally bound `List<CodeEntity>` to the DataSource you should be able to cast it back to that.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. The Datasource is null. Was trying to find a work around then just looping through the gridview.

Comment: Sometimes its the simple things :)  I've edited my answer below to include a null check (which I'm sure you know how to do).

Comment: My pleasure - anytime.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think the following should work:

```
if (gdvFGCode.DataSource != null)
{
    List<CodeEntity> codes = (List<CodeEntity>)gdvFGCode.DataSource;
}
```

**Edit**

Added `null` check on the Datasource and updated code to accurately reflect OP's code.

Comment: I tried but it said that it isnt a type. Is there any way to convert or declare the class I'm attempting to use as a type?

EDIT: Heres the class that I'm attempting to return into the list.

Comment: Can you edit your answer and post more of your code for your class and how you're using it?